# Complex Analysis - First Principles Proof of the Chain Rule

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, chain-rule

I'm trying to prove the chain rule for two complex-differentiable functions, from first principles, meaning a $\delta z$ proof.

We haven't covered Wirtinger derivatives, which keep popping up in various proofs.

I've made a start by making use of the small difference formula:
$$
\lim_{\delta z\to 0} g(z) + \delta z g'(z)  = \lim_{\delta z\to0} g(z + \delta z) 
$$

And I know that I could use this to complete the proof, just repeating the process on f, but I'd like it to be more rigorous as this formula is not something that's been presented in the course, I'm just using it as tool in this proof and so I want to be able to fully explain. So this is what I have:

$$
(f \circ g)(z) = \lim_{\delta z\to0} \frac{f(g(z + \delta z)) - f(g(z))}{\delta z}\\ 
=\lim_{\delta z\to0} \frac{f(g(z)+\delta z g'(z)) - f(g(z))}{\delta z}\\
=\lim_{\delta z\to0} \frac{f(g(z)) + \delta z g'(z) f'(g(z)) - f(g(z))}{\delta z}\\
=\lim_{\delta z\to0} g'(z) f'(g(z))\\
= g'(z) f'(g(z))
$$

So the trouble I'm having is expanding on what happens between line 2 and 3. I can do this for line 1 to 2, using the above formula, but for the next line I'm really stuggling to prove the formula holds.

Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof goes the same way as for the real chain rule :
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}f(g(z)) := \lim_{z'\rightarrow z}\frac{f(g(z'))-f(g(z))}{z'-z} = \lim_{z'\rightarrow z}\frac{f(g(z'))-f(g(z))}{g(z')-g(z)}\frac{g(z')-g(z)}{z'-z} = f'(g(z))g'(z)
$$
by definition of $f'$ and $g'$ (which are supposed to exist).

Comment: This proof does not work because the denominator of the first factor can take the value zero.

Comment: @PaulFrost How so ? The purpose of derivatives is to tackle such expressions as $0/0$ by a limit. Are you making reference to the case where $g$ is a constant function ? But in that special case, $\frac{f(g(z'))-f(g(z))}{z'-z'}$ vanishes straightforwardly because of the numeraror.

Comment: In the real case take $g(x) = x^2\sin\frac 1 x$. This is a non-constant function which has infinitely many zeros clustering at $0 = g(0)$. Thus the limit of the first factor does not exist for $x \to 0$. In the complex case this phenomemon cannot happen. If $g(z_n)= g(z_0)$ for a sequence $(z_n)$ converging to $z_0$, then $g$ must be constant. But this is a highly nontrivial theorem. The chain rule can be proved by elementary arguments.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682308/chain-rule-proof-verification

Comment: @PaulFrost Taylor expansion, that's a way for sure. But note that my expression can be regularized and is not totally invalid (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#First_proof).